# Why can't replace placeholder with format function in pymysql?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, format, placeholder, pymysql

How i create the table `mingyan`.

```
CREATE TABLE `mingyan` (
  `tag` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cont` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

It's said that string format function with `{}` is more pythonic way than  placeholder `%`.
In my scrapy to write some fields into a table `mingyan`.

```
self.cursor.execute("insert into mingyan(tag, cont) values (%s, %s)",(item['tag'],item['cont']))
```

It works fine in my scrapy,now i replace the placeholder way with string format function.

```
self.cursor.execute("insert into mingyan(tag, cont) values ({},{})".format(item['tag'],item['cont']))
```

The scrapy  got error info

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

Why can't replace placeholder with format function in pymysql?

The item in scrapy doucment.
[item meaning in scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html?highlight=item#item-fields)

Comment: What is your column type for tag and cont ? Should their values be in single quotes in the SQL query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: the parameter substitution implemented in `cursor.execute` is not the same as Python string formatting, despite the use of "%s" as a placeholder; that's why you get different results.

Databases expect query parameters to be quoted - surrounded by single or double quotes, even backticks - in specific ways.  Python's [DBAPI standard](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) provides parameter substitution functionality to automate the tedious and error-prone process of parameter quoting.

Database driver packages that implement the DBAPI standard automatically apply the correct quoting rules to query parameters.  So for example, given this code

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO mytable (foo, bar) VALUES (%s, %s);""", ('bar', None))
```

The driver will generate sql with this VALUES clause:

```
VALUES ('bar', NULL)
```

Observe that

- "bar" is in quotation marks
- `None` has been converted to NULL, and left unquoted

Using string formatting rather than DBAPI parameter substitution means you need to know and apply these rules yourself, for example like this:

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO mytable (foo) VALUES ('{}')""".format('bar'))
```

Note the quotation marks surrounding the format placeholder.

MySQL's quoting rules are discussed in detail in the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql).

Answer (score 0):

I always do the following

```
self.cursor.execute("insert into mingyan(tag, cont) values (%(tag)s, %(cont)s)", \
    {'tag': item['tag'], 'cont': item['cont']})
```

Answer (score 0):

Like in docs:
https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.Cursor.execute

> If args is a list or tuple, %s can be used as a placeholder in the
> query. If args is a dict, %(name)s can be used as a placeholder in the
> query.