# Why are records not getting inserted in table?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

Want to insert records into mysql with python but only **upload_date** is being inserted. mysql connection is made. *UserID1, link, desc, tag* are textvariables that store string typed in **tkinter EntryBoxes**. PLease help.

```py
userID1_info = userID1.get()
link_info = link.get()
desc_info = desc.get()
tag_info = tag.get()
cursor1 =  mycon.cursor()

now = datetime.now()
upload_date = now.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")

upload_query = "INSERT INTO link_manager(UserID, Links, Description, Tag, date_time) \
                VALUES ('{}','{}','{}','{}','{}')".format(userID1_info, link_info, desc_info, tag_info, upload_date)
cursor1.execute(upload_query)
mycon.commit(

)
```

No Error or any Exception is being returned when I run the program.
The data does get inserted but only the upload_date and the others are left blank in the mysql table.

Comment: Similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57534466/why-cant-replace-placeholder-with-format-function-in-pymysql/57561554#57561554